# How to find all K-th elements for each expiration time

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

I need ideas or suggestions to solve the following problem in the shortest possible execution time.

**Input:**

Given an array of integers *T = [t0, t1, t2, ... tk]* representing a row where each element is the maximum waiting time. And an array *E = [e0, e1, e2, ... ei]* representing all possible expiration times. Finally, an integer *K* is given which is the maximum size of a container.

**Problem:**

For each expiration time *E*, it is necessary to obtain the position of the last element *T* that was able to enter the container of size *K*, and each waiting time in *T* must be greater than or equal to the expiration time *E* to be able to enter the container.

**Example Case 1:**

Input:

*K = 2; T = [1, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 6]; E = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]*

Output:

*Kth = [2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0]*

**Explanation:**

1. In *E[0]*, the expiration time is 1, so the 2nd in row *T* will be the last to enter the container, so *Kth[0] = 2nd;*
2. In *E[1]*, the expiration time is 2, so the 3rd in row *T* will be the last to enter the container since the 1st element has expired, so *Kth[1] = 3rd*;
3. In *E[2]*, the expiration time is 3, so the 3rd in row *T* will be the last to enter the container since the 1st element has expired, so *Kth[2] = 3rd*;
4. In *E[3]*, the expiration time is 4, so the 3rd in row *T* will be the last to enter the container since the 1st element has expired, so *Kth[3] = 3rd*;
5. In *E[4]*, the expiration time is 5, in this case almost all elements of *T* except the last one have expired, however, as it was not possible to complete the container, it must return position *0*, therefore *Kth[4] = 0;*
6. And so on for *E[5]* and *E[6]*.

**Solution: (High Performance)**

1. For each element E, search in array T for elements that are greater than or equal to the expiration time E.
2. Count all the elements found in step 1, if the total is equal to K, the last position read is the Kth element.
3. Repeat step 1 for all elements of E.

```java
public static int[] kth(int k, int[] t, int[] e) {
        int[] kth = new int[e.length];

        if (k > t.length)
            return kth;

        Arrays.sort(e);
        int c = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {            
            for (int j = 0; j < t.length; j++) {
                if (t[j] >= e[i])
                    c++;

                if (c >= k) {
                    kth[i] = j + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (c < k)
                break;

            c = 0;
        }

        return kth;
}
```

Is there a faster way to get the k-th elements? (**solved**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting aside all the 'expiration time' and 'container size' language, I think your problem boils down to:

> Given integer k and integer lists E and T, find the kth element of T
>   that is larger than or equal to each element of E.

So for a specific element `e` the Java code might look like:

```
IntStream.range(0, T.size())
    .filter(i -> T[i] >= e).limit(k).max();
```

As far as I can see there are no potential optimisations of the algorithm for a specific element because you need to walk through each element to filter them (though this code may not be the most efficient implementation).

Because  you are calculating for each element in E, the most obvious optimisation is to cache results so you don't need to recalculate. For example, you could cache the list of k indices for each e that satisfy the condition so that when you calculate a larger e you can start by filtering those elements and then restarting your scan at the next highest element.

I can't guarantee that this is the optimal algorithm (which is what you requested). But, in general, there's really no such thing: the efficiency of an algorithm depends on the input data. For example the algorithm I describe above would be very inefficient if you had a single element in E as you would be storing and calculating cache data that was then not used.

Just as an additional tip, your final lines

```
List<Integer> kth = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < sizeE; i++) {
    kth.add(result[i]);
}
return kth;
```

Would be better expressed as `return Arrays.asList(result);`

Comment: The best solution I found to achieve high performance was to exchange the List / Streams for Arrays and removed the repeated cases